# push notification to get device location

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi i want to use push notification on android device and get device location for more information
I want to write application for android that when server want to get android device location push a notification timely to the device  and the application on the device send device location to server timely.
I can't use Cloud to device messaging service because this service need that user first online and after user is online send server notification with C2DM service!.But i want to send notification to device and get device location any time server wants.

Comment: were you able to do this ? @user1344766

Answer (score 0):

1. For any sort of push notification to be made possible, your client will need to be online. An offline client cant accept push notifications until it is online.
2. A C2DM push can be initiated by the server. No need for client to start it. The server just needs to send a message to the C2DM server and notification will be sent.
3. What you basically need to do is, on receiving the notification from C2DM server, make your C2DM base receiver call a function, which retrieves the clients location data using `LocationManager` and send it to the server.

EDIT for MQTT:

i havent done this much myself but it can be used for push service

You need:

an MQTT broker which runs on the server side, like the mosquitto broker which is Open Source.

an MQTT client library which you include in your Android app, enabling your app to connect, subscribe, and publish messages. refer this http://mqtt.org/software

to come up with a way of uniquely identifying users or devices, and then use that as a topic so that you can individually publish a message to one device.

Comment: C2DM server need android market that this application doesn't work in some countries! another choice is MQTT is this solution is ready to use?

Comment: i have edited the answer to cater to your query. do have a look.

Comment: also take a look at this  http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform